# Given $G:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$, find $F$ such that $G=\operatorname{curl}(F)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, curl

At my calculus II class we are studying multivariable functions and yesterday er talked about the curl operator (we used the definition in "usage" section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)).

The typical exercise we got as homework, was like: given a function $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$, compute $\operatorname{curl}(F)$ and so far so good. Today I got this homework which is exactly the opposite, i.e.
$$"\text{Let } \ G=\frac{x}{|x|^3}. \text{Find an example of } \ F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3 \text{such that } \ G=\operatorname{curl}(F)."$$

The exercise was proposed for $G=\frac{x}{|x|^3}$ and $G=\frac{x}{|x|^2}$, so I guess there is a similar strategy.

Could someone please help me in find an example even in only one of the cases?

I am thinking to examples like $F(x)= x/|x|$, or to some powers, but it is not working.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider $F(\vec x)=\dfrac1{\|\vec x\|}$

Comment: Hmm, it looks like divergence of $x / \lVert x \rVert^3$ is 0 as you'd expect from the curl of a vector field; but divergence of $x / \lVert x \rVert^4$ is nonzero so it can't be the curl of any vector field.

Comment: @user170231 what does $\|\cdot\|$ stand for?

Comment: It's just notation for the norm of a vector, which some people prefer using to distinguish it from the absolute value function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $x / \lVert x \rVert^3$ also cannot be the curl of any vector field defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ (0, 0, 0) \}$: if it were, then by Stokes' theorem, you would have to have $\iint_S G \cdot dn = 0$ for $S$ the unit sphere; but that integral is actually not zero.

Comment: @user170231 does $F(x)=1/\|x\|$ belong to $\mathbb R^3$? I do not see that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put $\langle1,1,1\rangle$ in the numerator, not $1$. In any case I'm not suggesting that *that* $F$ is a solution, rather a starting point, since its curl has $\|\vec x\|^3$ in the denominator. As for notation, if $\vec x=\langle x,y,z\rangle$, then $\|\vec x\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Comment: After struggling for almost 24 hours with the [Helmholtz decompositon theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) to solve this very interesting question I found an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3055531/949989):
$$
F(x,y,z)=\frac{z-r}{rs}\begin{pmatrix}y\\ -x\\0\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,,\quad s=x^2+y^2\,.
$$
I have checked numerically that it is correct.

Comment: @KurtG. thank you. How did you check it numerically?

Comment: Took a bit of python code, sampled uniform $x,y,z$, calculated curl numerically. This is at the end of 24 hours just a less tedious sanity check than ordinary calculus. Have you meanwhile done the latter to see if curl$F$ really is $G$?

Comment: Yeah, I checked it..by hand :)

Comment: Great. This is an amazing example one can learn a lot from. Have you also checked that the other $G$'s, say, $x/\|x\|^n$ with $n\not=3$ in $\mathbb R^3$ are not divergence free and therefore not such $F$ can exist?

Comment: @KurtG. I noticed this comment just now. Do you mean that the only case in which one find $F$ is the case $n=3$. It would be very very interesting.

Comment: Correct and fairly trivial because div rot is always zero. What I find a lot more interesting are the properties of those $F$ that can be found in $n=3$, One example is the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector field
$$
G(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad\text{ on }\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\},
$$
describes [Coulomb's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law#Vector_form_of_the_law) and
[Newton's law of universal gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation#Vector_form) and is mathematically interesting in many ways: It is rotation free and divergence free. A scalar function
whose gradient is $G$ is
$$
H(x,y,z)=-\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}}\,.
$$
The divergence freeness of $G$ suggests that there should be a vector field $F$ whose curl is $G\,.$ It turns out that

- $F$ exists but cannot be defined on all of $\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\}\,.$

This was briefly remarked in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4641974/949989). After some confusion on my side an finally learning it from Ted Shifrin I'd like to sum it up a bit: If $F$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\}$ one can apply Stokes' theorem to each hemisphere separately to conclude that the flux of $G$ through the whole unit sphere must be zero but this cannot happen because the flux of $G$ is
\begin{align}
\oint_{S^2}\hat{\mathbf{n}}\cdot G\,dS&=\oint_{S^2}\frac{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{smallmatrix}\right)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}}\cdot \frac{\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{smallmatrix}\right)}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}\,dS\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\varphi=4\pi\,.
\end{align}
To see that on the contrary Stokes' theorem leads to a flux of zero (assuming that $F$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\}$) note that the line integral of $F$ along the boundary of each hemisphere equals the flux of $\nabla\times F=G$ through that hemisphere. But these line integrals cancel out because of their opposite orientation which leads to zero flux. A contradiction.

- Consequently, when $F$ whose curl is $G$ exists there must be at least one point on one of the two hemispheres on which $F$ is not defined. An example for such an $F$ is
  $$
  F(x,y,z)=\frac1{r^2+rz}\begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\\0\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad r:=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}\,,
  $$
  which is a simpler notation for the solution found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3055531/949989). This $F$ is defined for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb R^3$ except on the ray $z\le 0,x=y=0$ (where $r+z$ becomes zero) and
  describes a clockwise circular motion around the $z$-axis and parallel to the $xy$-plane. A way to visualise it is to look at the speed of this motion
  which is
  $$
  \|F\|=\frac{\varrho}{\varrho^2+z^2+z\sqrt{\varrho^2+z^2}}\,,\quad\varrho:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,.
  $$
  The following picture shows this speed as a function of the distance $\varrho$ to the $z$-axis for various levels of $z\,.$ For  $z\le 0$ where $F$ is not defined on the $z$-axis the speed blows up when the $z$-axis is approached.

[image]

Another interesting picture shows the $[0,3\pi/2]$-sectors of the surfaces of constant speed $\|F\|\,.$
The blue surfaces has the slowest speed and the brown surface the highest.
These surfaces converge at the origin.

[image]

Further properties of $F\,:$

- The one-form
  $$
  \omega=\frac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{r^2+rz}
  $$
  is closed if and only if $z=0\,.$ This follows from $(\nabla\times F)_3=\partial_xF_2-\partial_yF_1=G_3=z/r^3\,.$ For $z=0$ this form has interesting properties that I summarized [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4605719/949989).
- On the unit sphere $S^2$ the speed of the integral curves can be written
  more simply as
  $$
  \|F\|=\sqrt{\frac{1-z}{1+z}}\,.
  $$
  This is zero at the north pole $z=1$ and infinite at the south pole $z=-1\,.$ The vorticity of this vector field
  is, as we know, $\nabla\times F=G$ which on $S^2$ is simply $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{smallmatrix}\right).$
  Due to the circular motion in planes parallel to the $xy$--axis this seems odd at points away from the poles.
  But this rotationally symmetric vorticity $G$ arises from different speeds of integral curves next to each other.
  In particular, near the equator we have practically a
  parallel flow with shear that has a nice animation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity#Examples).