# Paraboloid flux problem. Can I use z=0?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Consider the paraboloid
$B := \{(x, y, z) ∈ R^
3
: x^
2 + y^
2 = z, z < 1\}$
The flux $\int_
B
F · ν dS$(from
the inside out) of the vector field
$F : R
^3 → R
^3
, F(x, y, z) := (xy, xz, −zy)$

I am not sure if I am correct in doing this, but I use z=0, however I get $\iiint \text{div}\; \vec F . dV=F_1+F_2$ both $F_1, F_2$  are equal to 0. Should I use z=1? I am a bit lost here. Thanks for any given advice!

For the outer normal vector I get $(\frac{2x} {\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}}, \frac{2y} {\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}}, \frac{-1} {\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}})$

Comment: $z$ is not equal to $0$. $z$ is equal to $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: So should I do 3 integrations? dzdydx? And the domain of z would be [0,1]? of y[$-\sqrt {-x^2}, \sqrt {-x^2}$] and of x [0,1]?

Comment: Hint: how many integrations you do over a volume? over a surface? what $x,y,z$ are follows from the definition of $B$. $y$ is *certainly not* in the interval $[-\sqrt{\color{red}{-}x^2},\sqrt{\color{red}{-}x^2}]\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. How should I get the interval of y? Also is x [0,1] is correct?

Comment: Which $x,y,z$ satisfy $x^2+y^2=z,z<1\,?$ You are permitted to change this to $z\le 1\,.$ Now, for every fixed $z\in[0,1]$ can you tell me the ranges of $x$ and $y$? Hint: start fixing $x\in[0,z]\,.$ Why? $z$ is your radius.

Comment: $y\in [-\sqrt{1-x^2}, \sqrt{1-x^2}]$?

Comment: No.  $y\in [-\sqrt{\color{red}{z}-x^2},\sqrt{\color{red}{z}-x^2}]\,.$ and $x\in[0,\sqrt{z}]$ (correction to previous comment: $\sqrt{z}$ is the radius).

Comment: Before we do that cumbersome $3d$ integral in Cartesian coordinates. Can you first tell me the divergence of $F$ ?

Comment: @KurtG. if I take y as what you suggested I am getting integral of dy is =0

Comment: All of the substitutions are with y^2 so it will be 0 , what do I do?

Comment: The divergence of $F(x, y, z) := (xy, xz, −zy)$ is $y+0-y=0$ which leads to $\iiint{\rm div F}\,dV=0\,.$ What do we do now? Nothing. That was it.

Comment: Really? it could be that the flux of the vector field is simply 0 ? I was searching for a mistake.... Well in any case, thank you so much!!!!

Comment: You are welcome. For an example that is divergence free except in one point (and has non zero flux) please see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4644356/949989).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parameterize your paraboloid by $x$ and $y$, in which case $z$ is given by $z = x^2+y^2$. Integrate with respect to $x$ and $y$ replacing $z$ by $x^2+y^2$ everywhere and you should be fine. The paraboloid is a surface, it is two-dimensional, you are computing an integral depending on two variables.

Comment: Is the outer normal vector correct, then or should it be (x, y, x^2+y^2)?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: Which one? $(\frac{2x} {\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}}, \frac{2y} {\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}}, \frac{-1} {\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}})$?

Comment: Yes, that one is the correct one.

Comment: I want to ask, why is the ${\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}$ part come from squaring 2x+2y-1  individually and then taking the root of the whole? Will it always be like this? or how it is determined?

Comment: You want a unit vector. A vector of norm one. So you need to divide by the norm of the gradient. In the flux formula, this is the unit normal that appears.

Comment: Do you perhaps know what should be the domain of y? because I am getting 0

Comment: $x$ and $y$ belong to the unit disc, $D = \{(x,y) \in {\bf R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$. The final integral is probably easiest to compute in polar coordinates.