# Let $F=\frac{(x,y,z}{(a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2)^{1.5}}$ be a vector field. Is there a vector field $G$ such that $curl(G)=F$?

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

Let $A =\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus\{ (0,0,0)\},a,b,c>0$.

Let $F=\frac{(x,y,z}{(a^2x^2+b^2y^2+c^2z^2)^{1.5}}$ be a vector field.

Is there a vector field $G$ such that $curl(G)=F$ ?

I have no idea how to approach this problem , any help is welcome.

Comment: Hint: $\mathrm{div}(\mathrm{curl}(G)) = 0$ for any smooth vector field $G$.

Comment: In the special case $a=b=c=1$ that vector field describes Coulomb's law and Newton's law of universal gravitation. It is known that there is no vector field $G$ defined on all of $\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\}$ whose curl is $F\,.$ At least on a ray starting at the origin $G$ must have a singularity. But an expression for $G$ is known. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639896/given-g-mathbbr3-to-mathbbr3-find-f-such-that-g-operatornamecurl/4644356#4644356). The singularity of $G$ is also known as Dirac string.