# Can a cross-product of two $C_1$ gradient fields fail to be a curl?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $u,v : U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a pair of functions of class $C^2$ defined on an open set $U$. Is it possible to always find a field $F$ such that $\nabla u \times \nabla v = \text{curl} (F)$? My original intuition was that it wasn't possible to always do this and that the function $G: \mathbb{R}^{3} \setminus \{\vec{0}\} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ defined by $$G(x,y,z) := \left(\frac{x}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}},\frac{y}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}},\frac{z}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2 \right)^{3/2}},\right)$$ would somehow help prove this fact.

Comment: "I am trying to show that the converse of this result is not true for non-contractible regions."  Did you mean to write "converse of" here?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, I even wrote it! Perhaps I didn't explain myself properly, but the objective of the question I asked is to figure out if it is possible to find functions of class $C^2$, $u$ and $v$, defined in a non-contractible open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, in such a way that the cross product $ \nabla u \times \nabla v$ is not the curl of a field. I think this could be achieved with the function $G$, but this belief is only sustained by the fact that it is the only vector field in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ I know of that is not the curl of a field.

Comment: Right, so the objective is to show that the result (not its converse) is false for non-contractible regions.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I wrote the question badly. I'll correct it right away. Thank you!

Comment: The title is a mess. It seems to me, upon further reading, that you are asking if a cross-product of two $C^1$ *gradient* fields can fail to be a curl. Your "From Clairaut's Theorem" is placed at the wrong point of your second sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Ted! I changed the title and wording of the question to reflect your comments. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that your vector field $G$ cannot be a curl (say, because its flux across the unit sphere is nonzero). But note that
$$\nabla u\times\nabla v = \text{curl}(u\nabla v),$$
so your $G$ cannot be written as the cross-product of two gradients. To be explicit, in your title you now say that you want the cross-product of two gradients to fail to be a curl. That is impossible.

Comment: I didn't know that formula! Thank you very much for your help Ted!

Comment: I am a bit confused. The question about $G$ was raised [recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4639896/949989) and an answer was found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3055531/949989). In a more friendly notation the $F$ whose curl is $G$ should be $$F(x,y,z)=\frac{z-r}{rs}\begin{pmatrix}y\\ -x\\0\end{pmatrix}\,,\quad r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,,\quad s=x^2+y^2\,$$ I checked this numerically and the OP of the recent question verified it doing calculus.

Comment: @KurtG.: While it may be true that your $F$ satisfies $\text{curl}(F) = G$, it is not the case that $F$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, or even all of $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{0\}$.  In fact, as the OP pointed out, there is no vector field $F$ defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{0\}$ satisfying $\text{curl}(F) = G$.

Comment: @JesseMadnick . Then we agree. $G$ and $F$ are only defined on the punctured $\mathbb R^3$. BTW I checked again with a bit of wolfram alpha that curl$(F)=G$. Credit should go to user Anders Beta who found this four years ago in the link I posted.

Comment: @KurtG. We don’t agree. The domain of $F$ omits the entire $z$-axis; this is not the punctured $\Bbb R^3$. The question you linked is also beyond sloppy regarding domains.

Comment: @KurtG.: To reiterate, there is no vector field defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{0\}$ whose curl is $G$.  In particular, as Ted Shifrin correctly points out, your vector field $F$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{0\}$, but rather the subset $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{z\text{-axis}\}$.

Comment: The $z$-axis is only a coordinate singularity.  Since $(r-z)(r+z)=r^2-z^2=s$  we can write $F$ as
$$
F(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{r^2+rz}\begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\\0\end{pmatrix}\,
$$ and this is defined on the punctured $\mathbb R^3\,.$ This should be expected because this is where $G$ is defined and $G$ is rotationally symmetric. Needless to say that I checked again multiple times that this $F$ also satisfies $\nabla \times F=G$.

Comment: $F$ is defined whenever $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}>0\,.$ This rules out the origin but not the entire $z$-axis. Sorry I did not mean to be a pain. Just want to reach an agreement.

Comment: @KurtG. Then I guess Stokes’s Theorem fails. Your nonstandard notation messed me up, since i expect $r$ to be the polar coordinate. No agreement. As I stated at the outset, the flux of a curl across a closed surface must be $0$.

Comment: I hope Stokes' theorem does not fail. I will post my triple check as an answer to that recent related question. Lets see what comes out.

Comment: @KurtG Why is $r+z\ne 0$ on $\Bbb R^3-\{0\}$? Hint: It is not.

Comment: Right! This rules out the ray $z<0,x=y=0\,.$ Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, @KurtG. For future purposes, make sure that you understand the proof of the result I claimed from the outset. Then you will be more self-critical when you make assertions contradicting it!

Comment: You are (honestly) the last person here in MSE I would like to disagree with. Just trying to learn. Please allow me one more question. The $G$ in OP should have zero divergence.  I checked this and [others](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4639896/949989) did this too. So I am still a bit confused regarding the flux of it through a sphere.

Comment: @KurtG. The divergence theorem   does not apply because of the singularity. You have to apply Stokes’s Theorem to the surface integral of a curl; cut the surface into two pieces.